# How to verify ACL rules on Aruba without access to source and destination?

Tags: aruba

What kind of tools (without recommending any specific products), if any, are involved in testing ACL rules without actually making requests from potential source ip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is not specific to Aruba. Testing such things is the same, regardless of the router or firewall vendor.

There are penetration testing (pen test) tools and approaches that security experts use (you could try on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), but they will not recommend anything either).

Answer (score 1):

You can't synthesize or simulate the traffic on the switch triggering the ACL entries, but if the traffic is actually there, `show statistics` shows you the rule hits and can be *very* helpful:

```
show statistics aclv[4|6] {aclname} [port|vlan] {portno/vlanid}
```